# How to open new window browser when user click close tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, popup

I tried this code to open new window browser when user click close tab but it doesn't work

```
<script>

window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
    window.open("http://google.com");
window.stop();
};

</script>
```

So, can you give me any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. Opening a popup in response to the window being closed is [forbidden by the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup):

> An algorithm is allowed to show a popup if any of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> The task in which the algorithm is running is currently processing an
>   activation behavior whose click event was trusted.
>
> The task in which the algorithm is running is currently running the
>   event listener for a trusted event whose type is in the following
>   list:
>
> - change
> - click
> - dblclick
> - mouseup
> - reset
> - submit
>
> The task in which the algorithm is running was queued by an algorithm
>   that was allowed to show a popup, and the chain of such algorithms
>   started within a user-agent defined timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
  window.open('http://google.com','new','width=600,height=400,toolbar=1')

});
```

Guess that's the way.

Notice that most of browsers block pop-up windows by default.